# Porting ATMega8 AVR based program to Intel Curie Processor

Tags: atmega328, avr

I'm currently trying to port a program called 'ArduinoUSBLinker' to work on my Arduino 101 (which has an Intel Curie CPU instead of the standard ATMega CPU).

The program is used to flash ESCs without the need of additional hardware.
[Arduino USB Linker](https://github.com/c---/ArduinoUSBLinker)

Unfortunately the code is mainly based on the ATMega's built in AVR timers,
which uses several different predefined variables such as `TCCR0,TCCR1,TCTN2…`

These are not available (or are they?) in the Curie Module. Since the Arduino 101 has timer functionality, I was wondering if there is a way to translate those into the Curie Timer library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Those variables are the addresses of physical registers on the AVR that manipulate its timer/counters. Most other processors will have equivalent, but not likely identical, hardware. You'll need to port functionality, not the code.

You'll need to reverse-engineer (worst-case) the code you're trying to port (assuming you aren't intimately familiar with it, e.g., you designed it), develop a spec for it (at least in your head), and write to that spec for the Curie.

If the overall job is not (too heavily) processor-specific, you may be able to write it to be portable by writing the job-specific code in, e.g., in C, and call well-defined functions (in C or assembler) for the CPU-specific ones, that could easily be replicated on another processor.